# ContainsKey for Dictionary with HashSet keys unexpectedly returns false

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

Please, can anybody help me with my code?

I cannot understand why `ContainsKey` returns `false`.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<HashSet<string>, string>(HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer())
    {{new HashSet<string> {"Red", "Green"}, "Color"}};

var shouldBeTrue = dictionary.ContainsKey(new HashSet<string> {"Green", "Red"}); //true

var first = dictionary.Keys.First();
first.Add("Blue");

var shouldBeTrueButIsNot = dictionary.ContainsKey(new HashSet<string> {"Green", "Red", "Blue"}); //false
var shouldBeAlsoTrueButIsNot = dictionary.ContainsKey(first); //false
var referenceEquals = dictionary.Any(k => k.Key == first); //true
var equals = dictionary.Any(k => k.Key.Equals(first)); //true
```

Comment: A must read and understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons

Comment: You need to refresh your knowledge on Dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/hashtable-and-dictionary-collection-types

Comment: Objects used as keys must not be mutated after being added to a dictionary, at least not in ways that affect the equality being used for the key. See duplicate.

Comment: Sorry but really cannot read whole stackoverflow to find a duplicate. The title "Duplicate keys in Dictionary when using PhysicalAddress as the key" doesn't have very common with my problem.

Comment: Anyway thank you for reply, didn't realize that the hash is not updated in dictionary after change. My bad, I should get some rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've created a `HashSet` and inserted it into the `Dictionary`. Under the hood, a hash code was generated for that `HashSet` by the `Dictionary`, using the specified `IEqualityComparer` (which generates a hash code based on the elements within it - `Red` & `Green` in this case.

The `Dictionary` then stored that `HashSet` in its internal hash table using the hash code that was generated above. For the sake of having a pragmatic example, let's pretend the hash code that it generated was `123`.

You then *mutated* the existing `HashSet` by adding a new element. Here's the kicker though, it's *still stored in the `Dictionary` using the `old` hash code* (`123`).

When you perform a lookup on a `Dictionary` (using `ContainsKey`, in this case), the `Dictionary` first generates a hash code for the lookup record, and for every matching record in its internal hash table (yes, there may be multiple) it will then call the `Equals` method on those records to find the 'actual' matching element.

So why is all this important?

Well, if you remember, your initial `HashSet` had its hash code generated *based off the elements within it at that time*. So the hash code for `Red` & `Green` ended up being `123` in this example. If you were to call the comparer's `GetHashCode` on the very same `HashSet` *after* adding a new value, then the hash code would no longer be `123`, for example's sake, let's say it would actually be `999`.

So when you query the `Dictionary` using `ContainsKey` and passing in a new `HashSet` with `Green`, `Red` & `Blue`, its hash code is generated (`999`) and a lookup is done on the `Dictionary's` internal hash table -> **oops no records found with hash code `999`**.

Here's how you can prove it:

Remove the entry from the `Dictionary` and then re-add it before performing your lookups.
So the code would look like

```
        ...
        var first = dictionary.Keys.First();

        dictionary.Remove(first); // Remove the record before mutating it so it can be found using its hash code
        first.Add("Blue");
        dictionary.Add(first, "Color"); // Re-add it, triggering the generation of a new hash code
        
        var shouldBeTrueButIsNot = dictionary.ContainsKey(new HashSet<string> {"Green", "Red", "Blue"}); //false
        var shouldBeAlsoTrueButIsNot = dictionary.ContainsKey(first);
        var referenceEquals = dictionary.Any(k => k.Key == first);
        var equals = dictionary.Any(k => k.Key.Equals(first));
        ...
```

When you test your code with the changes above, you'll get the expected results. Also, the code above is *purely* for the sake of demonstrating the issue - it is not advised to use in practice.

I highly suggest you read up on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/hashtable-and-dictionary-collection-types) as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Actualy I was trying to remove the entry, but I was unable to. You can try it yourself, it doesn't work (remove returns false). Probably same reason as for ContainsKey.